# Casting BSTR as char* in a dll; different results depnding on VBA/C# caller

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll, casting

I have a dll function that takes BSTR parameters. These are cast as char* before being used for other things.

When the dll is called from VBA code this works. However, when it is called from C# code, only the first character is pointed to.

Both of these are Excel addIns for pre-2007 and 2007+ versions of Office, which call into a faster C++ AddIn. They call it directly, not through Excel.

The VBA function declaration:

```
Private Declare Function Test Lib "ExcelAddIn.xll" (ByVal param As String) As String
```

The C# function declaration:

```
[DllImport("ExcelAddIn.xll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
private static extern string Test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string param);
```

When debugging the dll and watching the input BSTR values, they appear to be correct from both; just the C# one only casts the first character.

`Charset=CharSet.Unicode` makes no difference.

C++ code.

```
BSTR __stdcall Test(BSTR param)
{
char* Param= "";

if(param!= NULL)
    Param= (char*)param;

    return OtherClass.DoOtherStuff(Param);
}
```

Comment: Can you see the bytes in debugger? Perhaps, one is in UTF-16 and another in ANSI encoding?

Comment: C# one is definately ANSI. What's the default for VB? Could be the answer.

Comment: You mentioned calling this from VB.  Do you mean VB.Net, or an older version?  I believe BSTR (aka Basic String) is the native string type for older VB versions.  Just wondering if that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Calling from VBA (Excel AddIn/Macros), not .NET.

Comment: Take a look at the answer @Rup just posted.  C++ and older VB (including VBA) use entirely different string formats.  Casting isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why has to do with the way you are marshalling the data.

The VB declaration contains no annotations on the `string` parameter and hence it will marshal as a normal `char*` parameter.  The CLR can do no type verification for pinvoke and essentially puts a `char*` in a slot which expects a `BSTR`.  Your code though immediately casts it to a `char*` and it fixes the marshalling problem.

In the C# example though you explicitly said to marshal the `string` as a `BSTR`.  A `BSTR` is actually a string which uses `wchar` under the hood.  By doing a simple cast to a `char*` you are essentially casting a `wchar*` to a `char*` which explains why you only see the first character.

The easiest solution is to just have the Test method take a `char*` parameter and remove the marshalling annotation on the C# version.

Comment: Did the job thanks, didn't think it would be that easy. Can't return char* strings back to VB though so that bit will stay the same.

Comment: why not simply add the necessary attributes to the VB code? (Yes, I realize that this requires changing the declaration syntax.)

Comment: @Konrad, that works too but then the C++ code would need to be changed as well to properly cast from a `BSTR` to a `char*`.  I don't know off hand how to do that cast properly so I suggested the route I knew :)

Answer (score 1):

BSTRs are Unicode strings. As you're seeing, if you try and use a LE Unicode string as ANSI you'll only get the first letter (if it's ASCII, etc.)

ATL / MFC's CComBSTR class might help: you can attach the BSTR you receive and I think it'll handle single-byte conversion for you. <s>It may also be safer to use this if you want Unicode strings internally - I don't think BSTRs are guaranteed to be zero-terminated (they have a length at index -1).</s>[edit] corrected by dkackman below, thanks.

Your best solution really would be to convert OtherClass to use Unicode strings not MBCS, or if it's only used in a COM context you could convert it to use BSTRs even. Your program will then better support internationalisation expanding your markets, etc. However this isn't always a simple conversion.

Comment: Can you explain why setting CharSet.Unicode in the C# declaration is having no effect? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: BSTR are always null terminated but null's are also valid characters within the string. That's why it was so easy to pass a VB string to WINAPI functions, but also the source of hard to find bugs.

Comment: @Toby Wilson I've never used that, sorry, but I expect it's for LPCTSTR parameters (i.e. Windows API TCHARs) not BSTRs and to select between -A and -W variants of API functions where they exist.

Comment: @dkackman Thanks, edited to fix - I haven't done COM for a few years.